# Outputting cerr using cout

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, iostream

I came across a piece of code that does basically the following:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << cerr << " Hi.";

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
0x601088 Hi.
```

First of all, why would anyone do 'cout << cerr' it does not make sense.
Second of all, what is the meaning of the output above?

Worth to mention that on my machine the above code compiles and executes without errors.

However a much more complex code (doing the same thing as above) on a different machine (server ssh connection) running the same version of gcc 5.4.0, produces this error when doing make (shortened for clarity):

```
error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’)
     cout << cerr << "DB: Field " + e.table + "[" + e.index + "]." + e.field
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Cerr is on output stream for warnings. If you overload the left shift operator it could be done

Comment: **It's a typo**, in all likelihood.  Two things are sent to `cout`.  The first thing isn't very meaningful, when printed.

Comment: shouldn't you be using `g++` instead of `gcc` for c++?

Comment: `cout << cerr << " Hi.";` is wrong, it doesn't make sense. It's either `cerr << " Hi.";` out `cout << " Hi.";`. From the error message you mention in your code, the author probably meant to write `cerr << "DB: Field " + e.table + "[" + e.index + "]." + e.field...`

Comment: g++ and gcc versions are the same

Comment: @François Andrieux That is great to know, but isnt gcc5.4.0 c++11 or am i thinking about it wrong?

Comment: @miro_x GCC 5.4.0 compiles by default with the flag `-std=c++03`, which mean it uses ISO C++03

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Until c++11, `std::basic_ios` offered an [implicit conversion to `void*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). This code won't compile with c++11 or later. You basically have this, which compiles with older versions of gcc :

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    void * x = std::cerr;
    std::cout << x << " Hi.";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is great. I suppose its no longer supported as there is never any reason to have cout << cerr am i correct?

Comment: @miro_x yes, `cout << cerr` was wrong from the beginning, it just happened to compile and when used it outputted the meningless value of a pointer before the actual error message.

Comment: @miro_x  The only reason to do that would be to know if the stream was in a failed state. The actual value of the returned pointer is meaningless beyond checking for `nullptr`. The conversion returned `nullptr` if the `fail()` would return true, and a non-`nullptr` otherwise. In any case, just convert the stream to `bool` or call `fail()` directly.